# Polycops and Robbers (Cops' Thread)

Tags: popularity-contest, cops-and-robbers, polyglot

### This is the cops' thread, the robbers' thread is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172222/polycops-and-robbers-robbers-thread)

A polyglot is a program, that without modification, can run in multiple languages.

---

## Allowed languages

Any language that was made before the challenge and isn't made for the purpose of the challenge, it is allowed, though discouraged, to use languages that are easy to recognize

---

## Cops' Challenge

To write a non-empty program that does one of the following tasks:

- Adds two numbers from STDIN
- Prints "Hello, World!"
- Prints the first 20 terms of the Fibonacci sequence

Then, list the languages it works in (it must do the same thing in all languages). When you first post your answer, it is *vulnerable*, and robbers will try to find more languages it works in other than the ones you specified. If any robber finds a language, they comment on your question saying they cracked it. You should then edit your question saying it got cracked and list the languages you were missing.

---

If a week passes by and nobody cracked your submission, you can mark it as *safe*, no robbers can crack it.

---

## Winning

Most upvoted safe answer is the winner.

---

## Extra rules

Cops must know there *is* a language that the program runs in other than the ones they wrote, so that there's a guarantee that all answers are *possible* to crack.

And as always, standard loopholes apply.

Comment: You should define what sort of languages you are allowing. Can it be a language newer than the challenge? And it would probably be a good idea for the cop to be able to demonstrate it's a polyglot in yet another language to mark it as safe, so all solutions are crackable.

Comment: @Okx I will define what languages are allowed, but I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: What is the winning criterion (i.e. how will answers be ranked after they are marked safe)?

Comment: @Doorknob Uhh, upvotes?

Comment: @dylnan Originally, no, but now that I think of it that's probably a good idea

Comment: @JoKing If a submission runs in any language, you can post it, and you should generally list all the languages you thought of except 1 of them

Comment: Different versions and different compilers are not different languages, correct?

Comment: @Stephen Correct.

Comment: The 20th digit of the Fibonacci sequence is the 2 in 233. Is this what you intended?

Comment: First time to see a CaR PopCon tbh. And maybe the 3rd task should be changd to "Prints the first 20 **terms** of Fibonacci sequence"?

Comment: @Nitrodon I meant the first 20 terms like Shieru said

Answer (score 7):

## Wow, cracked by [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172222/polycops-and-robbers-robbers-thread/172235#172235) while I'm still typing the explanations lol

```javascript
'<?php '//'; #@ SPELL,WITH,ME, ,H,E,L,L,O, ,W,O,R,L,D,"'Hello, World!'"
$a = "'Hello, World!'";
if ([])
 console.log($a);
else {
 for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($a) - 1; $i++)
  echo($a[$i]);
}
// ?>'
```

Prints `'Hello, World!'` (with single quotes) in both JavaScript and PHP. This should be an easy one to solve.

### How this works

`'<?php '//'; #@ SPELL,WITH,ME, ,H,E,L,L,O, ,W,O,R,L,D,"'Hello, World!'"`

JS treats this line as a string `'<?php '` followed by a `//` comment, and PHP prints `'` (outside the tag, so literally), then starts the script with open tag, and a string `'//'`, then a `#` comment.

`$a = "'Hello, World!'";`

Both JS and PHP defines the variable `a` to be the string `"'Hello, World!'"`.

```javascript
if ([])
 console.log($a);
```

In JS, since `[]` is consider truly, `console.log($a)` is executed and this prints out the string `"'Hello, World!'".

```javascript
else {
 for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($a) - 1; $i++)
  echo($a[$i]);
}
```

In PHP, since `[]` is consider falsy, the `for` loop is executed and this prints out the characters `Hello, World!` (notice the absence of quotes) subsequently.

`// ?>'`

In JS this is a comment, but in PHP the close tag ends the script and the `'` after the tag is printed out literally.

---

### Yes, the remaining language is Befunge-93.

`'<?php '//'; #@ SPELL,WITH,ME, ,H,E,L,L,O, ,W,O,R,L,D,"'Hello, World!'"`

`<` redirects the IP to the end of the line, then `"'Hello, World!'"` is pushed in reversed order. After that the 15 `,`s are used to output the characters (in normal order because of the double reversal). Finally `@` terminates the program.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172235/76162)

Comment: @JoKing lol I was still typing the explanations when you cracked this

Comment: By the way, you weren't meant to print it with single quotes

Comment: @FireCubez Hmmmm but it's cracked anyway -- It's impossible to tell the cracker to delete his answer, is it? btw I had a pure JS+Befunge-93 one before, but that's just obvious and with too few languages.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Well it doesn't give you any advantage so it's fine I guess

Comment: Wait, don't unknown characters reverse the IP?

Comment: I swear even though I’ve seen this answer for 3 weeks this is the first time I realized the polyglot language wasn’t named “Wow”

Comment: @FireCubez A number of Befunge-93 interpreters do this, but it isn't part of the specifications. Befunge-98 *does* reflect though

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "Wow" language?

Comment: @a'_' The language was not Wow; It was PHP and Befunge-93

Comment: Oh I meant JS, PHP and Befunge-93

Answer (score 5):

## Almost all Befunges, Safe!

```
 &<v
@.+<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0HNpozLQU/b5v9/QwMFIwMFAA)

Starting it off with an easy one. This is adds two numbers from STDIN in every version of Befunge, 93, 96, 97, 98 etc. Thanks to Johnathan Allen for reminding me about Trefunge, Quadfunge, and all those variations as well. This doesn't work in Unefunge though.

---

#### The answer is [Flobnar](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flobnar)!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJT8pLLPr/X0HNpozLQU/b5v9/QwMFI4P/uikA)

By the makers of Befunge, Flobnar is described as "what happens when you get Befunge drunk". It uses a lot of the same instructions, but goes backwards in comparison, starting at the `@`.

```
....
@...   Start here going left

....
..+<   Sum above the + and below

..&.   Both end up here and get input as a number
....

Implicitly output the return value
```

I thought someone would have gotten it since I've done a few things in Flobnar recently.

Comment: Is there another language you know it works on?

Comment: @FireCubez Yes, there is a language without the word `funge` in it that adds two numbers from STDIN

Comment: I was thinking of `Trefunge` for a second, but it has `funge` in it. Anyways your answer is safe now since a week has passed

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) and [M](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/m), 15 bytes

```
+19Ð¡1-4181ḢFḊĊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/b0PLwhEMLDXVNDC0MH@5Y5PZwR9eRrv//AQ)

Prints the first 20 terms in the Fibonacci sequence.

Hexdump is

```
1B 21 29 0F 00 21 1D 24 21 28 21 B5 36 B1 B0
```

*Edit*: Three weeks and no crack? This shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: Congratulations on this being safe!

Comment: But what is the working language?

Answer (score 2):

## Hello World, Cracked

```
puts "Hello World!"
```

List of Languages it works in (minus a few :D):

05AB1E

05AB1E (Legacy)

2sable

Oasis

Ruby

Tcl

Cracked:

Working Language is Foo

Comment: Do I have to find all the languages it works in, or just one?

Comment: Just one, I'm pretty sure it works in a lot of languages

Comment: Ah, shoot, I didn't see Tcl at the end of your answer :(

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172578/76162) Always be careful with quotes

Comment: why are you so good!

Comment: It also works with Crystal.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, vulnerable

Also works in Coconut (Thanks BMO!)

Also works in Cython (which is a superset of Python, so why wouldn't it)

Adds two inputs together

<s>(may have some garbage output before the output when run in the second language, let me know if that's not okay)</s>

No longer has garbage output

Hint: The language name is somewhere on this page.

```
"""
" "- Z B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ K O.a- F R.d " "" "" "- C P.u- O T.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- T I.q- O K.a " "" "" "- H C.n- G Y.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W C.a+ M T.a " "" "< D N.h] V T.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D K.b- M S.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U Y.u- I J.x " "" "" "" "" "[ X C.e- K U.m " "" "" "> L W.y+ F X.l " "" "" "+ D B.n+ V N.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L F.g+ T Q.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< L Z.f] V I.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I O.s+ D F.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D P.g. W B.j" "+ J S.z+ X U.l " "" "+ J A.o+ L V.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R P.x+ Y L.j " "" "" "+ H W.s. Q P.l " "" "" "" "" ". N U.d+ C K.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U B.h+ W L.n " "" "" ". X L.k[ Q Y.v " "" "" "- F B.r- B X.z " "" "" "" "" "- M F.t> W L.v " "" "" "" "" "+ O W.x< F W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "] L P.y> M A.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I K.x- F A.i " "" "" "" "" "- Z U.a- M M.t " "" "" "- C L.s. C C.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- T R.u- N U.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- U R.p[ F D.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S P.o> C H.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O W.p+ N W.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U A.r< O A.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] A M.y> W H.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". G J.g- L M.p " "" "" "" "" "[ J K.k- P E.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S V.y- U U.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> P T.v+ Z F.h" "< X R.g] J A.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> A U.f- U G.u " "" "" "" "- P L.o- I V.q " "" "" "" "" "" ". B Y.b+ H Y.r " "" "" "" "" "+ O Y.u+ P N.w " "" ". F K.n- D L.c " "" "" "" "" "- I G.g- D Y.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B Y.h- S H.x " "" "" "" "- N R.k. K A.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- N F.r- F S.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Q L.e- L J.f" "- S Q.o- K U.k " "" "- C I.h- A N.s" ". N P.t- D J.b " "" "" "" "" "" "[ I S.t- D A.j " "" "" "" "" "" "- N F.a- Z S.b " "" "" "" "" "> A G.g+ Z N.g " "" "< A K.t] U W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "> V D.b. Y U.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K F.j+ G M.t " "" "+ J E.c+ X S.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K F.r+ Z R.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S X.p+ Q R.h " "" "" "" "" "+ E L.p+ J U.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F G.z. K S.s " "" "" "- Y O.k- C P.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- H N.v- O C.k " "" "" "" "- S J.x- H O.p " "" "" "- X D.p- W E.h " "" "" "- K F.v- B X.q " "" "" "" "- M Z.a- W E.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". N Y.a+ T H.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R S.c+ U Q.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U D.s[ U L.o " "" "" "" "- E U.u> V C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N U.d+ E H.x " "" "" "" "" "< M W.v] C S.i " "" "" "" "> F U.p+ G F.a " "" "" "" ". G S.c- K C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "[ M J.p- R G.w " "" "> Z M.q+ Z J.e " "" "" "" "+ Y Q.k+ S L.c " "" "" "" "" "+ Q R.i< Y C.l " "" "" "" "" "] L F.h> M K.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". Z K.q- K R.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Q R.u- W L.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D C.g- Z T.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> L G.u+ R M.h " "" "" "+ G U.c< R C.s " "" "] N D.n> W T.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I X.d- W Q.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". H Z.a- P C.n " "" "- F P.i- R O.x " "" "- R R.w- J Q.j " "" "- H R.y- C D.y " "" "" "" ". L A.t+ K C.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ G P.o- N N.j " "" "- Q V.x- S V.b " "" "" "" "> U K.u+ Q F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "< M U.v] P I.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> S U.t. U G.t " "" "" "+ Z N.k[ X Y.t " "" "" "" "- E Y.v> L W.c" "+ K S.g+ S B.h " "" "" "+ K V.a< Z C.z " "" "" "] G C.n> J Z.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U K.t- G V.o " "" "" "" "" "- K Z.f[ K J.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- J B.l- S N.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O L.w> G J.z " "" "" "+ X V.y< G F.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] M V.z> L N.x" "- Z R.r. V R.x " "" "" "" "[ G R.h- D O.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W I.g+ R C.x " "" "" "" "+ S F.h+ B G.m " "" "< B G.f] L D.z " "" "" "" "" "> F O.a+ K M.h " "" "" "" "" "" "+ V F.x. P V.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C X.z. A L.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ M J.b+ I O.t " "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z Y.q. N I.h" "- T W.e[ W K.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S M.a- P O.d " "" "" "" "" "- B T.g> W K.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D V.g< O J.f " "" "" "" "" "" "] O O.r> C Z.f " "" "- W L.b. P F.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y P.t[ H O.h " "" "" "" "- O Z.c- C A.z " "" "" "" "" "- X Y.g- O Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "- N E.n> G C.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B I.g< Z P.a " "" "" "] H F.y> G J.j " "" "" "" "" "" "+ N R.u. G D.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- A F.e- P C.i " "" "" "" "- W L.i- L V.d " "" "" "" "" "" "- X P.r- Y S.x " "" "- F C.n- G N.o" "- Z A.q. K Q.j " "" "" "" "" "" "[ S B.n- W C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N Q.g- O M.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> J T.f+ M N.h " "" "" "" "" "" "< O C.w] J E.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> F N.c. Z H.d " "" "" "" "" "" "- G M.n- L S.x " "" "" "" "" "" "- S Z.h- C M.l" ". C S.z+ G I.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ D W.g- C P.j " "" "- H V.t- C T.p " "" "" "" "- F F.o> Y A.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O R.g< I V.h " "" "" "" "" "" "] D H.p> H D.j " "" "" "" "" "+ O G.c+ I Z.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S R.f. I J.m " "" "" "" "" "" "+ H Z.l+ X V.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Y M.m- L O.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> B Z.n+ D W.x " "" "" "" "+ Z C.m+ X Q.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< S E.w] L Y.n" "> V F.b. V S.z " "" "+ C M.n+ L K.n" "+ S S.y+ S O.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R G.y+ K X.j " "" "" "" "+ F O.g+ A C.z " "" "+ R L.q. S N.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ X L.x+ C F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C O.x. G A.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Z L.u- A P.o " "" "" "" "- O H.i> U Q.v" "+ F A.d+ E T.n " "" "" "+ B S.o+ F B.y " "" "" "+ L S.r< O X.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "] C D.h> H O.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ X O.x+ H Q.b " "" "+ E S.n. M X.q " "" "" "- D S.j- U E.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ H J.g- A R.a " "" "" "" "> T X.s+ D C.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ G X.p+ I J.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F K.i< C Q.h" "] X L.c> X V.i " "" "" "" "" "+ B Q.t. S J.j " "" "" "" "" "- L J.v- D C.h " "" "" "" "" "" "- F D.f- R N.u " "" "" "" "" "" "- T Y.p- R S.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V S.y- X U.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- H E.r- H O.l" ". I A.a+ C S.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S B.q+ L N.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.u+ L X.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V C.b. K P.l" "- U K.l[ P S.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z E.u- P M.s " "" "" "" "" "" "- I P.z- A W.f " "" "" "" "> W A.x+ S B.l " "" "" "" "" "" "< P H.m] T C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D N.o+ H T.w " "" "" "+ H X.n+ S Y.g " "" "" "" "" ". L C.b- M N.h " "" "" "" "" "- D B.q- X C.s " "" "" "" "" "" "[ D Y.o- L W.z " "" "" "> D N.n+ C P.o " "" "" "" "" "+ A V.a+ X X.w " "" "" "" "" "+ L T.l< V K.s" "] C E.f> C I.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O C.a- L B.a " "" "- E Q.c- I F.h " "" "" "" "" "" "- A Y.q- K T.a" "- C Y.h- F A.e " "" "" "" "" "" "- M D.h- L I.z " "" "" "" "" "- X G.c- M F.x " "" "" "" "- P U.s. N F.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ A E.c+ F B.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q K.f+ W I.y " "" "" "" "" "+ E S.a+ R S.o " "" "" "+ N Y.a. J G.u " "" "+ L V.i+ X T.y " "" "" "+ S F.l+ O Y.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q V.e+ S Q.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O A.g+ W S.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z D.e[ N A.l " "" "" "" "- A D.b> I K.a " "" "" "" "" "" "+ E U.c+ E O.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ P D.h< G K.g " "" "" "" "" "] G X.b> H W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K D.c+ H B.f " "" "" ". K Z.e+ M P.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". A L.n- O B.m" "- P T.z- C S.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Q Y.e[ I N.g " "" "- X A.q> Y L.i" "+ I Y.u+ T A.w " "" "+ B Z.t< W U.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "] R S.i> U S.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O T.a- M D.f " "" "" "" "" "" "- H U.s- V O.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O H.p- O L.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- X R.b- U V.w " "" "" "" "" "" "- G H.w- E R.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R J.c- H S.p " "" "" "" "- J A.x. F W.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ J R.s- F R.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> L H.w+ Z A.z " "" "" "" "+ Z O.s+ S D.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< B C.k] J F.k" "> P C.t+ H C.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N B.e. V S.t " "" "" "" "" "[ Q M.p- M C.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B A.r- Q C.y " "" "" "> F D.t+ A G.r " "" "< A V.d] X H.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> J E.x- Y P.d " "" "- E T.h- P I.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R O.f. I B.f" "+ P M.n+ N L.j " "+ N Z.c[ Y V.z " "" "" "- K G.k> D F.u " "" "" "+ L D.e+ W I.k " "" "" "" "" "" "+ P M.k< X Y.y " "" "" "" "" "" "] O L.n> Q K.e " "" "" "" "+ R M.t+ C B.i " "" "" ". E J.g+ I C.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C C.k+ B I.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ T U.d+ K D.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F K.p+ M O.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q H.e. M Z.a " "" "" "" "+ I Q.m+ W M.d " "" "" "" "+ A I.y+ G H.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E U.j. Z W.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- G X.r- R V.h " "" "- I P.a- M X.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V M.q- C M.z " "" "" "" "" "" "- P K.l- N L.r " "" "" "" "" "" ". L D.t- G A.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ T J.f- M X.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V P.t- G Z.f " "" "> T O.h+ S Q.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< Z S.r] D P.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> G Q.n- F M.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P Z.g. N S.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E G.x[ U N.t " "" "" "- R J.z> Y Y.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V N.x+ V U.s " "" "" "" "" "+ W P.s< S P.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] G O.x> X J.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ X E.l. Z T.o " "" "" "" "+ T N.l+ L U.t " "" "" "" "+ C L.i+ Z M.g" "+ M K.k+ E P.p " "" "" "" "" "+ P T.l+ S Z.h" ". F W.k- Q D.q " "[ O I.r+ K W.r " "" "" "+ J B.x> F A.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y D.b- O H.r " "" "" "" "" "" "- W N.a< H S.e" "] N F.o> Q I.y " "" "" "" "" "" "+ B V.w. Q G.b " "" "" "- J R.i[ B M.j" "- Q R.a- K V.v " "" "" "- M S.b> W O.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C D.t+ T X.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< S C.m] T F.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E Q.z- O B.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". Z T.a+ X L.t" "+ H U.f+ B E.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K A.c+ A E.p " "" "" "" "" "+ S N.v+ P P.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R C.f+ I I.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N C.h. U P.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D Q.c- I K.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- U U.c- A X.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N B.u. A J.p " "" "" "" "" "[ N K.j+ L H.t " "" "" "" "" "+ D E.j> T Q.c" "- B U.z- A N.e " "" "" "- C J.k< D O.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] O U.c> Z J.e " "" "" "" "" "" "+ K E.m+ B O.p" ". H S.l[ T N.r " "- Z M.e> D Q.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K B.v+ S P.o " "" "" "" "" "+ Q O.w< Y D.o " "" "" "" "] I C.n> R H.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I F.z. L Q.t " "" "[ W U.q- A C.q " "" "" "" "- H U.l- V P.f " "" "" "- J Z.n> C Y.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E Y.b< J Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "] F W.x> X H.c " "" "+ Z X.r+ O K.g " "" "" "" "+ Y Q.f. X Z.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ O G.z- F K.u " "" "> P Z.o+ M D.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L G.h+ Z M.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< J L.y] O U.x " "" "" "" "" "> L K.q+ P U.c " "" "" "" ". F H.l+ X W.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N I.x. U A.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y B.m[ X W.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B X.u- V G.w " "" "" "" "" "- D N.d> M Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ I I.w< E P.u " "" "] F V.k> I U.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- F P.b- B H.u " "" "" "" "" "" ". J X.n+ G E.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U J.t[ T C.l " "" "" "" "" "- O K.g> T L.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ W A.a+ O Z.g " "" "+ A N.e< Q N.q " "" "" "" "" "] W U.k> Y J.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V V.k+ Y L.w " "" "" "" ". S V.k+ P C.h " "" "" "" "" "" "+ C G.v+ N F.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K P.u+ R J.z " "" "+ E R.y+ I I.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y H.z+ G U.v " "" "+ T E.o+ G S.g " "" "" "" ". S A.u. Z X.n " "" "- L S.x[ M X.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V Z.e- S C.p " "" "" "" "" "- T H.m> E B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q T.t< N Z.g " "" "" "] R I.y> B J.k " "" "" "" "" ". V V.r- L T.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ L Z.s- T Y.p " "" "" "" "" "" "- N A.p- W X.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- M D.t> Z Y.r " "" "" "" "+ B Q.u< L C.m" "] V R.j> Z D.y " "+ A C.j+ P S.w " "" "" "" ". V K.r- E N.s " "" "" "" "" "- C F.n- Q B.p " "" "" "" "" "" "[ R E.d- H Y.r " "" "" "" "" "" "> H D.v+ X E.h" "+ V R.j+ C C.m " "+ C Q.j< Q X.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] Y J.g> K Y.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". T R.i- K R.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B U.o- Z I.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I X.s- G D.p" "- B C.i- K G.c " "- V G.i- P Y.f " "" "" "" "- V G.t- U D.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- K P.f. F X.m " "" "" "" "" "- O B.l- S C.e " "" "" "" "" "" "- B K.l. D Z.f " "" "- U K.m- J F.z " "" "" "" "[ H N.l- D G.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y T.u- Z R.s " "" "> Z O.p+ D V.g" "< Q W.w] W K.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> O V.l- I A.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". B L.j+ H C.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B W.w[ H T.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z F.z- H S.u" "- K B.j> M T.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q N.d+ G K.a " "" "" "" "" "" "< W U.e] H M.u " "" "" "" "" "> B Q.u. O J.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z G.n- H K.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I E.j- X U.y " "" "" "" "" "- L O.u- J D.h " "" "" "- X F.q- P J.v " "" "- E T.u- X M.c " "" "" "" "" "- S P.y. U S.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E C.l+ S N.y " "" "+ T N.r+ J F.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U I.x+ I P.o " "" "" "" "+ F Z.e+ P E.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ G J.k+ X Y.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z Z.d+ Y B.b " "" "+ F A.d. R W.p " "" "" "- M A.z- Y R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z L.a- E X.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I G.d- H J.b " "" "- U E.n. H X.k " "" "" "- V E.s- S F.h " "" "" "" "[ L A.x- A C.l " "" "" "" "- P O.q- X J.x " "" "" "> M X.u+ W H.s " "" "" "< H T.p] V U.o " "" "" "" "" "> P Z.v- C K.a " "" "" "- U J.p. V N.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ L T.u- N K.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I G.u+ Z N.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ H K.j+ M S.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< F M.t] D J.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E K.d+ J M.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O M.u. A P.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R V.v+ U I.e " "" "+ Z C.m+ L L.m " "" "" "" "" "+ B Z.d+ O R.s " "" "" "" "" "" ". B D.m- W R.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- W H.b. S R.g " "" "- Y N.a- P L.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ T M.k- D H.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P I.s- U A.z " "" "" "" "> E B.m+ O I.t " "" "" "" "" "< T N.c] A D.t " "" "" "> Q I.y- Z P.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". M B.t- N E.j " "" "" "- K T.z- Y S.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ D J.x- V R.z" "> R Q.i+ C G.h " "" "+ Z V.a+ U C.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D U.s< W C.x " "" "" "" "" "" "] F A.j> J L.h " "" "" "" "" "" ". N U.r- R F.n " "" "" "" "" "- V N.s- T L.n " "" "" "" "- V E.i- T G.n" "- O M.r- Z A.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- A Q.h- S Z.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- Q G.q- L X.p " "" "- Z D.k. M C.a" "- P M.e- V S.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S I.k- B W.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C W.o- U U.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V C.o. Q F.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P N.w- S Y.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ J R.h- D A.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N A.o- Q L.g " "" "> P L.c+ L T.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "< O W.o] P O.v " "" "" "" "" "" "> K G.h- T O.j " "" "" "" "" ". P J.u[ O W.x " "" "" "" "" "" "- I F.c- N Z.c" "- S U.e- L D.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E Y.l+ X Y.l " "" "" "" "" "" "< L S.q] P K.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D V.l+ M F.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F F.f+ C N.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". E D.d- P J.p " "" "" "" "" "" "- Q Z.c- E T.w " "" "" "" "" "[ O E.t- C G.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> D F.a+ S X.d " "" "" "" "+ V Z.a+ O V.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ I Z.z< N H.f " "" "" "" "" "] E L.n> U V.m " "" "" "" ". G E.r- P T.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- H U.p- N J.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D W.g- Q P.f " "" "" "" "" "" "- I S.w- L L.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O S.j- I W.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- F J.m- Q D.s " "" "" "- T C.v. F L.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C J.k. Z B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y J.r+ B G.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ P P.c+ T F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U A.k+ A W.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L R.s+ U U.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z B.t+ C J.g " "" "" "" ". Z Q.v+ Q W.l " "" "" "[ M C.i- J A.p" "- N V.p- V V.s " "" "- V O.v> M C.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ M O.f< I U.j" "] A G.b> Z D.z " "" "" "" "" "+ O J.h+ X K.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y I.r. Y E.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V P.s- R I.g " "" "- Q J.u[ V I.e " "" "" "" "" "- D B.g- C Z.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C E.f- U K.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z P.e> D N.y " "" "" "" "" "+ V K.k+ A J.b" "< C E.l] B E.t " "" "" "> D R.p. D L.a " "" "" "" "+ A H.q+ H Y.w " "" "" "" "+ K A.o. M X.k " "" "" "" "- M C.o- B N.c " "" "- F T.w- J F.u " "" "" "" "" "- N Q.i- W K.j " "" "" "- D V.q. E W.g " "" "" "+ C X.p+ R T.y" "+ R P.j+ B S.a " "" "+ D B.i. M G.c" "+ N B.l[ I N.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z R.w- P W.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C B.h- R P.m " "" "" "" "> S I.t+ H L.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< G O.e] T Z.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> A Q.k+ N V.q " "" "" "" "" "+ E S.y+ D C.n " "" "" "" ". U E.f- Z A.p" "[ Y C.q- D O.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D R.g- M A.k " "" "" "" "" "> Q D.j+ D E.r " "" "" "" "+ W W.p< E T.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] V P.g> G E.x " "" "" "- L O.p. S P.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.q+ G X.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ W X.q+ O E.o" "+ E Z.v. Q G.w " "[ H H.n- C F.x " "" "" "- N L.j- Z N.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- L G.e- F Y.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> C L.l+ T R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q F.e< Z D.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] W I.i> S T.z " "" "" "" "+ V Z.s+ Y W.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". R C.e+ O A.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ J P.b[ H W.i " "" "" "" "" "" "- L F.u- H D.k" "- H Q.w> L Y.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.p+ J U.y " "" "" "< X U.c] N E.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W M.k. J W.n " "" "" "> C K.i- T R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ S A.c- D W.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R I.g- M F.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I V.e+ Q U.j " "" "" "< T U.p] I C.j " "" "" "" "" "> W E.t- U O.y " "" "" "" "" "- I S.l. H M.t " "" "" "" "[ A Z.w- F H.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- M A.p- S J.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> F X.s+ F A.a" "< P A.c] I G.r " "" "> Y W.m- K F.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V W.e. G Q.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S C.t+ F W.y " "" "" "" "+ I S.v. N Y.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U Q.f+ V K.f " "" "+ N S.m+ W Y.u " "" "" "+ X X.j+ I I.m " "" "" "" "" "" "+ V I.g+ B Z.f" ". Q Q.q- L A.e " "" "" "" "" "" "[ F O.w- Z K.v " "" "- P I.b- M X.r " "" "" "" "" "" "- H O.n> I R.e " "" "" "+ V S.b< P U.a " "" "" "" "] Y G.g> S C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ X I.z+ P I.n"+ Q E.q" ""- Z B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ K O.a- F R.d " "" "" "- C P.u- O T.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- T I.q- O K.a " "" "" "- H C.n- G Y.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W C.a+ M T.a " "" "< D N.h] V T.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D K.b- M S.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U Y.u- I J.x " "" "" "" "" "[ X C.e- K U.m " "" "" "> L W.y+ F X.l " "" "" "+ D B.n+ V N.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L F.g+ T Q.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< L Z.f] V I.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I O.s+ D F.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D P.g. W B.j" "+ J S.z+ X U.l " "" "+ J A.o+ L V.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R P.x+ Y L.j " "" "" "+ H W.s. Q P.l " "" "" "" "" ". N U.d+ C K.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U B.h+ W L.n " "" "" ". X L.k[ Q Y.v " "" "" "- F B.r- B X.z " "" "" "" "" "- M F.t> W L.v " "" "" "" "" "+ O W.x< F W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "] L P.y> M A.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I K.x- F A.i " "" "" "" "" "- Z U.a- M M.t " "" "" "- C L.s. C C.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- T R.u- N U.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- U R.p[ F D.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S P.o> C H.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O W.p+ N W.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U A.r< O A.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] A M.y> W H.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". G J.g- L M.p " "" "" "" "" "[ J K.k- P E.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S V.y- U U.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> P T.v+ Z F.h" "< X R.g] J A.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> A U.f- U G.u " "" "" "" "- P L.o- I V.q " "" "" "" "" "" ". B Y.b+ H Y.r " "" "" "" "" "+ O Y.u+ P N.w " "" ". F K.n- D L.c " "" "" "" "" "- I G.g- D Y.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B Y.h- S H.x " "" "" "" "- N R.k. K A.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- N F.r- F S.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Q L.e- L J.f" "- S Q.o- K U.k " "" "- C I.h- A N.s" ". N P.t- D J.b " "" "" "" "" "" "[ I S.t- D A.j " "" "" "" "" "" "- N F.a- Z S.b " "" "" "" "" "> A G.g+ Z N.g " "" "< A K.t] U W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "> V D.b. Y U.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K F.j+ G M.t " "" "+ J E.c+ X S.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K F.r+ Z R.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S X.p+ Q R.h " "" "" "" "" "+ E L.p+ J U.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F G.z. K S.s " "" "" "- Y O.k- C P.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- H N.v- O C.k " "" "" "" "- S J.x- H O.p " "" "" "- X D.p- W E.h " "" "" "- K F.v- B X.q " "" "" "" "- M Z.a- W E.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". N Y.a+ T H.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R S.c+ U Q.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U D.s[ U L.o " "" "" "" "- E U.u> V C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N U.d+ E H.x " "" "" "" "" "< M W.v] C S.i " "" "" "" "> F U.p+ G F.a " "" "" "" ". G S.c- K C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "[ M J.p- R G.w " "" "> Z M.q+ Z J.e " "" "" "" "+ Y Q.k+ S L.c " "" "" "" "" "+ Q R.i< Y C.l " "" "" "" "" "] L F.h> M K.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". Z K.q- K R.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Q R.u- W L.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D C.g- Z T.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> L G.u+ R M.h " "" "" "+ G U.c< R C.s " "" "] N D.n> W T.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I X.d- W Q.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". H Z.a- P C.n " "" "- F P.i- R O.x " "" "- R R.w- J Q.j " "" "- H R.y- C D.y " "" "" "" ". L A.t+ K C.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ G P.o- N N.j " "" "- Q V.x- S V.b " "" "" "" "> U K.u+ Q F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "< M U.v] P I.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> S U.t. U G.t " "" "" "+ Z N.k[ X Y.t " "" "" "" "- E Y.v> L W.c" "+ K S.g+ S B.h " "" "" "+ K V.a< Z C.z " "" "" "] G C.n> J Z.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U K.t- G V.o " "" "" "" "" "- K Z.f[ K J.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- J B.l- S N.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O L.w> G J.z " "" "" "+ X V.y< G F.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] M V.z> L N.x" "- Z R.r. V R.x " "" "" "" "[ G R.h- D O.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W I.g+ R C.x " "" "" "" "+ S F.h+ B G.m " "" "< B G.f] L D.z " "" "" "" "" "> F O.a+ K M.h " "" "" "" "" "" "+ V F.x. P V.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C X.z. A L.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ M J.b+ I O.t " "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z Y.q. N I.h" "- T W.e[ W K.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S M.a- P O.d " "" "" "" "" "- B T.g> W K.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D V.g< O J.f " "" "" "" "" "" "] O O.r> C Z.f " "" "- W L.b. P F.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y P.t[ H O.h " "" "" "" "- O Z.c- C A.z " "" "" "" "" "- X Y.g- O Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "- N E.n> G C.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B I.g< Z P.a " "" "" "] H F.y> G J.j " "" "" "" "" "" "+ N R.u. G D.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- A F.e- P C.i " "" "" "" "- W L.i- L V.d " "" "" "" "" "" "- X P.r- Y S.x " "" "- F C.n- G N.o" "- Z A.q. K Q.j " "" "" "" "" "" "[ S B.n- W C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N Q.g- O M.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> J T.f+ M N.h " "" "" "" "" "" "< O C.w] J E.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> F N.c. Z H.d " "" "" "" "" "" "- G M.n- L S.x " "" "" "" "" "" "- S Z.h- C M.l" ". C S.z+ G I.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ D W.g- C P.j " "" "- H V.t- C T.p " "" "" "" "- F F.o> Y A.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O R.g< I V.h " "" "" "" "" "" "] D H.p> H D.j " "" "" "" "" "+ O G.c+ I Z.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S R.f. I J.m " "" "" "" "" "" "+ H Z.l+ X V.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Y M.m- L O.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> B Z.n+ D W.x " "" "" "" "+ Z C.m+ X Q.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< S E.w] L Y.n" "> V F.b. V S.z " "" "+ C M.n+ L K.n" "+ S S.y+ S O.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R G.y+ K X.j " "" "" "" "+ F O.g+ A C.z " "" "+ R L.q. S N.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ X L.x+ C F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C O.x. G A.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ Z L.u- A P.o " "" "" "" "- O H.i> U Q.v" "+ F A.d+ E T.n " "" "" "+ B S.o+ F B.y " "" "" "+ L S.r< O X.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "] C D.h> H O.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ X O.x+ H Q.b " "" "+ E S.n. M X.q " "" "" "- D S.j- U E.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ H J.g- A R.a " "" "" "" "> T X.s+ D C.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ G X.p+ I J.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F K.i< C Q.h" "] X L.c> X V.i " "" "" "" "" "+ B Q.t. S J.j " "" "" "" "" "- L J.v- D C.h " "" "" "" "" "" "- F D.f- R N.u " "" "" "" "" "" "- T Y.p- R S.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V S.y- X U.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- H E.r- H O.l" ". I A.a+ C S.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S B.q+ L N.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.u+ L X.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V C.b. K P.l" "- U K.l[ P S.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z E.u- P M.s " "" "" "" "" "" "- I P.z- A W.f " "" "" "" "> W A.x+ S B.l " "" "" "" "" "" "< P H.m] T C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D N.o+ H T.w " "" "" "+ H X.n+ S Y.g " "" "" "" "" ". L C.b- M N.h " "" "" "" "" "- D B.q- X C.s " "" "" "" "" "" "[ D Y.o- L W.z " "" "" "> D N.n+ C P.o " "" "" "" "" "+ A V.a+ X X.w " "" "" "" "" "+ L T.l< V K.s" "] C E.f> C I.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O C.a- L B.a " "" "- E Q.c- I F.h " "" "" "" "" "" "- A Y.q- K T.a" "- C Y.h- F A.e " "" "" "" "" "" "- M D.h- L I.z " "" "" "" "" "- X G.c- M F.x " "" "" "" "- P U.s. N F.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ A E.c+ F B.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q K.f+ W I.y " "" "" "" "" "+ E S.a+ R S.o " "" "" "+ N Y.a. J G.u " "" "+ L V.i+ X T.y " "" "" "+ S F.l+ O Y.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q V.e+ S Q.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O A.g+ W S.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z D.e[ N A.l " "" "" "" "- A D.b> I K.a " "" "" "" "" "" "+ E U.c+ E O.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ P D.h< G K.g " "" "" "" "" "] G X.b> H W.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K D.c+ H B.f " "" "" ". K Z.e+ M P.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". A L.n- O B.m" "- P T.z- C S.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Q Y.e[ I N.g " "" "- X A.q> Y L.i" "+ I Y.u+ T A.w " "" "+ B Z.t< W U.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "] R S.i> U S.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". O T.a- M D.f " "" "" "" "" "" "- H U.s- V O.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O H.p- O L.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- X R.b- U V.w " "" "" "" "" "" "- G H.w- E R.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R J.c- H S.p " "" "" "" "- J A.x. F W.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ J R.s- F R.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> L H.w+ Z A.z " "" "" "" "+ Z O.s+ S D.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< B C.k] J F.k" "> P C.t+ H C.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N B.e. V S.t " "" "" "" "" "[ Q M.p- M C.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B A.r- Q C.y " "" "" "> F D.t+ A G.r " "" "< A V.d] X H.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> J E.x- Y P.d " "" "- E T.h- P I.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R O.f. I B.f" "+ P M.n+ N L.j " "+ N Z.c[ Y V.z " "" "" "- K G.k> D F.u " "" "" "+ L D.e+ W I.k " "" "" "" "" "" "+ P M.k< X Y.y " "" "" "" "" "" "] O L.n> Q K.e " "" "" "" "+ R M.t+ C B.i " "" "" ". E J.g+ I C.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C C.k+ B I.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ T U.d+ K D.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F K.p+ M O.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q H.e. M Z.a " "" "" "" "+ I Q.m+ W M.d " "" "" "" "+ A I.y+ G H.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E U.j. Z W.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- G X.r- R V.h " "" "- I P.a- M X.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V M.q- C M.z " "" "" "" "" "" "- P K.l- N L.r " "" "" "" "" "" ". L D.t- G A.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ T J.f- M X.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V P.t- G Z.f " "" "> T O.h+ S Q.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< Z S.r] D P.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> G Q.n- F M.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P Z.g. N S.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E G.x[ U N.t " "" "" "- R J.z> Y Y.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V N.x+ V U.s " "" "" "" "" "+ W P.s< S P.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] G O.x> X J.d " "" "" "" "" "" "+ X E.l. Z T.o " "" "" "" "+ T N.l+ L U.t " "" "" "" "+ C L.i+ Z M.g" "+ M K.k+ E P.p " "" "" "" "" "+ P T.l+ S Z.h" ". F W.k- Q D.q " "[ O I.r+ K W.r " "" "" "+ J B.x> F A.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y D.b- O H.r " "" "" "" "" "" "- W N.a< H S.e" "] N F.o> Q I.y " "" "" "" "" "" "+ B V.w. Q G.b " "" "" "- J R.i[ B M.j" "- Q R.a- K V.v " "" "" "- M S.b> W O.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C D.t+ T X.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< S C.m] T F.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E Q.z- O B.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". Z T.a+ X L.t" "+ H U.f+ B E.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K A.c+ A E.p " "" "" "" "" "+ S N.v+ P P.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R C.f+ I I.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N C.h. U P.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D Q.c- I K.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- U U.c- A X.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N B.u. A J.p " "" "" "" "" "[ N K.j+ L H.t " "" "" "" "" "+ D E.j> T Q.c" "- B U.z- A N.e " "" "" "- C J.k< D O.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] O U.c> Z J.e " "" "" "" "" "" "+ K E.m+ B O.p" ". H S.l[ T N.r " "- Z M.e> D Q.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K B.v+ S P.o " "" "" "" "" "+ Q O.w< Y D.o " "" "" "" "] I C.n> R H.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I F.z. L Q.t " "" "[ W U.q- A C.q " "" "" "" "- H U.l- V P.f " "" "" "- J Z.n> C Y.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E Y.b< J Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "] F W.x> X H.c " "" "+ Z X.r+ O K.g " "" "" "" "+ Y Q.f. X Z.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ O G.z- F K.u " "" "> P Z.o+ M D.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L G.h+ Z M.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< J L.y] O U.x " "" "" "" "" "> L K.q+ P U.c " "" "" "" ". F H.l+ X W.j " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ N I.x. U A.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y B.m[ X W.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B X.u- V G.w " "" "" "" "" "- D N.d> M Q.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ I I.w< E P.u " "" "] F V.k> I U.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- F P.b- B H.u " "" "" "" "" "" ". J X.n+ G E.e " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U J.t[ T C.l " "" "" "" "" "- O K.g> T L.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ W A.a+ O Z.g " "" "+ A N.e< Q N.q " "" "" "" "" "] W U.k> Y J.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ V V.k+ Y L.w " "" "" "" ". S V.k+ P C.h " "" "" "" "" "" "+ C G.v+ N F.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ K P.u+ R J.z " "" "+ E R.y+ I I.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y H.z+ G U.v " "" "+ T E.o+ G S.g " "" "" "" ". S A.u. Z X.n " "" "- L S.x[ M X.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V Z.e- S C.p " "" "" "" "" "- T H.m> E B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q T.t< N Z.g " "" "" "] R I.y> B J.k " "" "" "" "" ". V V.r- L T.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ L Z.s- T Y.p " "" "" "" "" "" "- N A.p- W X.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- M D.t> Z Y.r " "" "" "" "+ B Q.u< L C.m" "] V R.j> Z D.y " "+ A C.j+ P S.w " "" "" "" ". V K.r- E N.s " "" "" "" "" "- C F.n- Q B.p " "" "" "" "" "" "[ R E.d- H Y.r " "" "" "" "" "" "> H D.v+ X E.h" "+ V R.j+ C C.m " "+ C Q.j< Q X.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] Y J.g> K Y.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". T R.i- K R.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- B U.o- Z I.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I X.s- G D.p" "- B C.i- K G.c " "- V G.i- P Y.f " "" "" "" "- V G.t- U D.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- K P.f. F X.m " "" "" "" "" "- O B.l- S C.e " "" "" "" "" "" "- B K.l. D Z.f " "" "- U K.m- J F.z " "" "" "" "[ H N.l- D G.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Y T.u- Z R.s " "" "> Z O.p+ D V.g" "< Q W.w] W K.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> O V.l- I A.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" ". B L.j+ H C.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B W.w[ H T.q " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z F.z- H S.u" "- K B.j> M T.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q N.d+ G K.a " "" "" "" "" "" "< W U.e] H M.u " "" "" "" "" "> B Q.u. O J.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z G.n- H K.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I E.j- X U.y " "" "" "" "" "- L O.u- J D.h " "" "" "- X F.q- P J.v " "" "- E T.u- X M.c " "" "" "" "" "- S P.y. U S.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ E C.l+ S N.y " "" "+ T N.r+ J F.s " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U I.x+ I P.o " "" "" "" "+ F Z.e+ P E.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ G J.k+ X Y.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z Z.d+ Y B.b " "" "+ F A.d. R W.p " "" "" "- M A.z- Y R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z L.a- E X.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- I G.d- H J.b " "" "- U E.n. H X.k " "" "" "- V E.s- S F.h " "" "" "" "[ L A.x- A C.l " "" "" "" "- P O.q- X J.x " "" "" "> M X.u+ W H.s " "" "" "< H T.p] V U.o " "" "" "" "" "> P Z.v- C K.a " "" "" "- U J.p. V N.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ L T.u- N K.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I G.u+ Z N.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ H K.j+ M S.h " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< F M.t] D J.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E K.d+ J M.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ O M.u. A P.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ R V.v+ U I.e " "" "+ Z C.m+ L L.m " "" "" "" "" "+ B Z.d+ O R.s " "" "" "" "" "" ". B D.m- W R.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- W H.b. S R.g " "" "- Y N.a- P L.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ T M.k- D H.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P I.s- U A.z " "" "" "" "> E B.m+ O I.t " "" "" "" "" "< T N.c] A D.t " "" "" "> Q I.y- Z P.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". M B.t- N E.j " "" "" "- K T.z- Y S.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ D J.x- V R.z" "> R Q.i+ C G.h " "" "+ Z V.a+ U C.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ D U.s< W C.x " "" "" "" "" "" "] F A.j> J L.h " "" "" "" "" "" ". N U.r- R F.n " "" "" "" "" "- V N.s- T L.n " "" "" "" "- V E.i- T G.n" "- O M.r- Z A.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- A Q.h- S Z.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- Q G.q- L X.p " "" "- Z D.k. M C.a" "- P M.e- V S.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- S I.k- B W.o " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C W.o- U U.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V C.o. Q F.i " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- P N.w- S Y.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ J R.h- D A.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- N A.o- Q L.g " "" "> P L.c+ L T.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "< O W.o] P O.v " "" "" "" "" "" "> K G.h- T O.j " "" "" "" "" ". P J.u[ O W.x " "" "" "" "" "" "- I F.c- N Z.c" "- S U.e- L D.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> E Y.l+ X Y.l " "" "" "" "" "" "< L S.q] P K.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "> D V.l+ M F.a " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ F F.f+ C N.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". E D.d- P J.p " "" "" "" "" "" "- Q Z.c- E T.w " "" "" "" "" "[ O E.t- C G.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> D F.a+ S X.d " "" "" "" "+ V Z.a+ O V.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ I Z.z< N H.f " "" "" "" "" "] E L.n> U V.m " "" "" "" ". G E.r- P T.n " "" "" "" "" "" "- H U.p- N J.v " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D W.g- Q P.f " "" "" "" "" "" "- I S.w- L L.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- O S.j- I W.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- F J.m- Q D.s " "" "" "- T C.v. F L.z " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ C J.k. Z B.m " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y J.r+ B G.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ P P.c+ T F.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ U A.k+ A W.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ L R.s+ U U.b " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Z B.t+ C J.g " "" "" "" ". Z Q.v+ Q W.l " "" "" "[ M C.i- J A.p" "- N V.p- V V.s " "" "- V O.v> M C.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ M O.f< I U.j" "] A G.b> Z D.z " "" "" "" "" "+ O J.h+ X K.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Y I.r. Y E.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V P.s- R I.g " "" "- Q J.u[ V I.e " "" "" "" "" "- D B.g- C Z.f " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C E.f- U K.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z P.e> D N.y " "" "" "" "" "+ V K.k+ A J.b" "< C E.l] B E.t " "" "" "> D R.p. D L.a " "" "" "" "+ A H.q+ H Y.w " "" "" "" "+ K A.o. M X.k " "" "" "" "- M C.o- B N.c " "" "- F T.w- J F.u " "" "" "" "" "- N Q.i- W K.j " "" "" "- D V.q. E W.g " "" "" "+ C X.p+ R T.y" "+ R P.j+ B S.a " "" "+ D B.i. M G.c" "+ N B.l[ I N.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- Z R.w- P W.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- C B.h- R P.m " "" "" "" "> S I.t+ H L.n " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "< G O.e] T Z.w " "" "" "" "" "" "> A Q.k+ N V.q " "" "" "" "" "+ E S.y+ D C.n " "" "" "" ". U E.f- Z A.p" "[ Y C.q- D O.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- D R.g- M A.k " "" "" "" "" "> Q D.j+ D E.r " "" "" "" "+ W W.p< E T.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] V P.g> G E.x " "" "" "- L O.p. S P.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.q+ G X.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ W X.q+ O E.o" "+ E Z.v. Q G.w " "[ H H.n- C F.x " "" "" "- N L.j- Z N.t " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- L G.e- F Y.y " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> C L.l+ T R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ Q F.e< Z D.g " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "] W I.i> S T.z " "" "" "" "+ V Z.s+ Y W.r " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". R C.e+ O A.d " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ J P.b[ H W.i " "" "" "" "" "" "- L F.u- H D.k" "- H Q.w> L Y.c " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ B F.p+ J U.y " "" "" "< X U.c] N E.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> W M.k. J W.n " "" "" "> C K.i- T R.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "[ S A.c- D W.w " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- R I.g- M F.p " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> I V.e+ Q U.j " "" "" "< T U.p] I C.j " "" "" "" "" "> W E.t- U O.y " "" "" "" "" "- I S.l. H M.t " "" "" "" "[ A Z.w- F H.x " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "- M A.p- S J.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "> F X.s+ F A.a" "< P A.c] I G.r " "" "> Y W.m- K F.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "- V W.e. G Q.u " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ S C.t+ F W.y " "" "" "" "+ I S.v. N Y.k " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ". U Q.f+ V K.f " "" "+ N S.m+ W Y.u " "" "" "+ X X.j+ I I.m " "" "" "" "" "" "+ V I.g+ B Z.f" ". Q Q.q- L A.e " "" "" "" "" "" "[ F O.w- Z K.v " "" "- P I.b- M X.r " "" "" "" "" "" "- H O.n> I R.e " "" "" "+ V S.b< P U.a " "" "" "" "] Y G.g> S C.l " "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "+ X I.z+ P I.n""";import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(input())+ast.literal_eval(input()))
```

Comment: What does the program do?

Comment: Uhm - there is a possibility that there are more but at least [Coconut](http://coconut-lang.org/) is backwards compatible w/ Python you might want to add that to your list..

Comment: @BMO Wow, TIL Coconut has so many shortening features I didn't even know I wanted in python.

Comment: @Quintec: It is an awesome language, the only problem is that the transpiler is horribly slow :(

Comment: Okay, it's not brainfuck

Comment: @BMO Thanks for the catch, I'll add it as supported if my PC stops screaming because of the size of that line in the code block :P

Comment: @FireCubez Are you okay with junk output? I can fix it if not.

Comment: @famous1622 I can't allow junk output, how'd I see the rrsult?

Comment: @FireCubez Reading the last line, obviously. In all seriousness I'll fix it though :Ehehe:

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - Hello, World!

```py
3;s="!dlroW ,ollexH";(print(s[-1]+s[-3::-1]),")")#"`[;:].
```

(Second language technically doesn't print a newline, but the interpreter adds one automatically)

...I just realised that I failed to read the date of the challenge, and the secondary language postdates the challenge. Many apologies.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes, safe

```
”Ÿ™,‚ï!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPcozsetSzSedQw6/B6xf//AQ)

Also works in

- 05AB1E (legacy)
- 2sable

Comment: I actually think the only thing it could be is some obscure 05AB1E-based golfing language. What is it?

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 39 bytes, safe

```
vdvII$$$$$$$$$>r+n;O@
>ri68*-i~i68*-^u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/vyylzNNTBQbsirTzrP0duOyKMs0stHQz68BUXKnC//@GCoYA)

Works in ><>, Gol><>, somehow not *><>, and *Backhand*.

### Explanation

```
vdv                   Push the speed down twice
   II                 Take 2 inputs
     $$$$$$$$$>r      A bunch of stuff that do nothing
                +     Add
                 n;   More nothing
                   O  Output
                    @ End
```

Answer (score -1):

## Hello, World!, cracked

```
#|
print("Hello, World!")# wh|#(write-line "Hello, World!")
```

This works in Python, Lisp, and <s>one other language</s> [Deadfish~](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish~).

Comment: Err, any language with `#` as a comment character and a `print` function, e.g. [Perl](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/1@5hqugKDOvREPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUlTWaG8RlmjvCizJFU3JzMvVQFdwf//AA)

Comment: It's not really safe, since I commented a solution half an hour after you posted it. I just assumed you were going to change it, since it works in a large amount of languages, [Julia](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/1@5hqugKDOvREPJIzUnJ19HITy/KCdFUUlTWaG8RlmjvCizJFU3JzMvVQFdwf//AA), [R](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7mGq6AoM69EQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSVNZobxGWaO8KLMkVTcnMy9VAV3B//8A) etc.

Comment: Alright, I'd just crack it despite JoKing's comments. [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201801/92069).